# How to specify that function argument type is any Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular v5 app written in typescript, I'm trying to create a function that accepts an argument which will always be an angular component. Any angular component. Is there an interface / abstract class which all Angular components implement that I can specify as the type? I initially tried to specify the argument type as `Component` (e.g. `function test(param: Component)`), before realizing that I was specifying that the argument type was the `Component` decorator, rather than the actual component.

I can't seem to find a S.O. answer (or question) asking this specifically.

Comment: Did you try: `test(myComponent: Type<any>) { ... }` ?

Comment: @Talavera I believe this is the answer, consider providing it with reference quote and link.

Comment: Angular [live example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vbdkjyjgekd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fad-item.ts) show same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is:

- If you know the type(s) of the component(s)

  `test(myComponent: Type<MyComponent1 | myComponent2>) { ... }`
- If you don't know it:

  `test(myComponent: Type<any>) { ... }`

Take a look at the [offical Angular Type doc's](https://angular.io/api/core/Type)

Comment: Awesome thanks! The docs seem to be pretty limited on this subject, do you know if `Type` is specifically an interface for `Component` or is it an interface for `Directive` (and hence would include component)? This is really a separate question, but if `Type` is just an interface for `Component`, do you know if there's an interface for `Directive`? I don't actually need this at the moment, but I imagine one day I might.

Comment: I think Type should be valid for both because according to the code it "Represents a type that a Component or other object is instances of." and if you see the sources it extends Function which is a Javascript basic.